# Lambda alias in Xon.sh and pipes

Tags: python, shell, lambda, pipe, xonsh

Why this peaces of code dont't run the same.

```
samuel@corny ~ $ echo "pippo\npluto\nminnie\ntopolino" | @(lambda a,s=None: s.read())                                 
pippo
pluto
minnie
topolino
```

Second command

```
samuel@corny ~ $ echo "pippo\npluto\nminnie\ntopolino" | @(lambda a,s=None: s.readlines())                            
pippo
pluto
```

Is the python **readlines** uncorrect for read line by line the input Pipe.

My version of Xon.sh is 0.7.8

Answer (score 1):

So this is somewhat subtle, but [callable aliases](https://xon.sh/tutorial.html#callable-aliases) (which lambdas are one type of), have a few different kinds of objects that they can return.  One of which is a tuple of `(stdout, stderr, returncode)`.

The `str.readlines()`  method returns a list, which in this case is `['pippo\n', 'pluto\n', 'minnie\n', 'topolino\n']`.  So, here,

- `stdout = "pippo\n"`
- `stderr = "pluto\n"`
- `returncode` is never printed, but happens to be `"minnie\n"` here

This is probably not the intended behavior and is why the first example works.